# How to delete a specific email using only uid

Tags: python, python-2.7, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to delete an email remotely using python's imap4 library and the email's uid value. I have tried using this code but it hasn't worked.

```
mail.store(uid,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
mail.expunge()
```

How do I delete this particular email?

Comment: You might also want to consider IMAPClient (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient). It makes working with UIDs somewhat easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UIDs, you need to use UID store:

```
mail.uid('STORE', uid,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
mail.expunge()
```

Don't mix message sequence numbers (fetch, store, search) with UIDs (uid fetch, uid store, uid search).  You might delete the wrong message all together!